# Oraclize: callback contain no result Error

Tags: solidity, json-rpc, oracles

I have the following contract to get a random number from 1 to 6 from random.org:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;
import "github.com/oraclize/ethereum-api/oraclizeAPI.sol";

contract RandomOrg is usingOraclize {
    string public res;

    event Log(string text);

    function RandomOrg() {

        Log("Created!");
    }


    function __callback(bytes32 myId, string _result) {
        if (msg.sender != oraclize_cbAddress()) revert();


        res = _result; // 'result' is the random number generated by random.org
        Log(res);
        updateNumber();

    }

    function updateNumber() payable {
        string memory query = "https://www.random.org/integers/?num=1&min=1&max=6&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new";
        oraclize_query(0, "URL", query);
    }

}
```

When using MetaMask and Oraclize dev IDE, the contract is successfully created, however, when calling the `updateNumber()` function (with or without msg.value, result is the same), I'm getting the following error:

```
callback contain no result Error: JsonRpcEngine - response has no error or result for request:
{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "id": 255617697,
  "method": "eth_estimateGas",
  "params": [
    {
      "from": "0x3768372d20afe96dde0c27677b916046cd32002d",
      "to": "0xe931380cb4389dce98227e095e41c9927433504e",
      "data": "0x1b6a2481",
      "value": "0xde0b6b3a7640000"
    }
  ]
}
```

What could be the reason of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Riccardo from Oraclize here.

I used:

1. **Metamask** on **Rinkeby** testnet;
2. **Value** for the `updateNumber()`: 1ETH;
3. **Gas price**: 20gwei

I just tried this contract from REMIX and worked:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;
import "./oraclizeAPI_0.5.sol"; //API copied from the oraclize github folder

contract RandomOrg is usingOraclize {
    string public res;

    event Log(string text);

    function RandomOrg() {

        Log("Created!");
    }


    function __callback(bytes32 myId, string _result) {
        if (msg.sender != oraclize_cbAddress()) revert();


        res = _result; // 'result' is the random number generated by random.org
        Log(res);
        updateNumber();

    }

    function updateNumber() payable {
        string memory query = "https://www.random.org/integers/?num=1&min=1&max=6&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new";
        oraclize_query(0, "URL", query);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, it did work, although I'm not sure why I was getting the JSON error.